# touch screen foil behind 5mm thick glass

Tags: lcd, touchscreen, tft

I wish to make a small project that will enable me to control my tablet\ipad behind my shower glass door.
I want to be able to put the tablet behind the glass and control it from the other side of the glass door.

I though about connecting a capacitive touch foil to the tablet and placing it between the glass and the tablet so the capacitivity should work.
I also though about connecting a lcd screen with an overlay touch foil and using otg or mhl for connecting it to the tablet.

What do you think would be a good way of implementing it and how ?

Thanks a lot
C

Comment: Wondering what is so important you need to use the tablet while you are having a shower, or whatever else you are doing in there, that a zip lock baggy would not fix.

Comment: You might want to put something on the front-facing camera, by the way. Having a camera pointed at you while showering might not exactly inspire trust in their host if you have guestts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that would even work. A capacitive touch screen depends on the "finger side" of the screen not being conducting laterally, and soapy water is a pretty good conductor. Much like a [V.I.C.E.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236907/are-electric-linear-solenoids-the-best-option-to-push-a-capacitive-screen-button/236926#236926) (**V**egetable **I**nterface **C**ontact **E**ntities):

[image: V.I.C.E]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I would like to use youtube or control some music app while taking a shower :)
As far as I know, this problem is not different then all those store windows that allows padestrians interacting with a lcd/rear projection screen using capacitive touch foil.

Comment: yes, but these only get wet with rain water, which is a bad conductor. Soap water is a good conductor. and also, these public touch screens can really be annoying, and generally aren't good at multitouch etc. It's not all that easy, I'm afraid. If you just want volume control etc, what about water-proof keys?

Comment: Thanks, thats actually a great idea ! I would need to have a full size keyboard for qwerty support.Can you explain why the conductivity of the soap water matters for this project ? Thanks again !

Comment: capacitive screens work by detecting where a well-conducting object touches the surface. With a wet surface, you basically touch everywhere at once. Just go ahead and try: put a large drop of water on your smartphone's screen and touch that drop. Is the action happening exactly where your finger was, reliably?