# Touch screen reacts exclusively skin and stylus, how?

Tags: touchscreen

I noticed that with my Android phone, the only things that it will respond to when tapped by are my skin and a stylus. It won't respond to taps by anything else. Not a toothbrush, not my hair, not a rough blanket, nothing other than my skin and a stylus. Why is this? Why does it not respond to taps from objects other than my skin and a stylus? Is there something about the microscopic properties of a stylus and my skin that makes it only respond to those taps? Why does it only respond to these 2 and nothing else?

Comment: Capacitive Sensing.

Comment: Try something metallic or a wet tissue, this will work as well

Comment: Whatever touches the screen needs to conduct electricity to some degree. Metal does, human bodies do, wet things generally do but plastic things generally don't. Have a good read of this [Wikipedia article on touchscreens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchscreen) for a more detailed explanation than you can expect anyone to write out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your touchscreen uses [Capacitive sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing).

This **only** works when the touch object is **electrically conductive**, at the same time some minimum size area needs to be "touched" so that's why not even all conductive objects will work.

The objects you mention are non-conductive so cannot work with a such a touch screen.

Comment: reminds me of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236907/are-electric-linear-solenoids-the-best-option-to-push-a-capacitive-screen-button/236926#236926

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had not seen that one before. Another thing we can add to to long list of functions which potatoes can perform ;-)